# How to retrieve firebase data for android

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I develope my app using Firebase. Now my query is I find out data from Firebase but not setup it on my object my Firebase data strucre is look like below image

[image]

My code is

```
mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            adapter=new LiveNewsAdapter(dataSnapshot);
            newsList.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

My Adapter class is

```
public class LiveNewsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LiveNewsAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private DataSnapshot mDataset;


public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView mTextView;

   public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
       mTextView=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvNewsView);
    }
}

// Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
public LiveNewsAdapter(DataSnapshot myDataset) {
    mDataset = myDataset;
}

// Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public LiveNewsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                               int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.text_livenews, parent, false);
    // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}

// Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    // - get element from your dataset at this position
    // - replace the contents of the view with that element
    System.out.println("DARA  "+ mDataset.getValue());




    for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: mDataset.getChildren()) {
        String name = (String) messageSnapshot.child("Divya Bhaskar").getValue();
        String message = (String) messageSnapshot.child("Sandesh").getValue();

        System.out.println("NMAE  : "+name);
    }

}

// Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (int) mDataset.getChildrenCount();
}
```

}

plase help my out how to setup `Datasnapshot` value in `TextView`